# .net cookie authentication for specific URLs

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, setcookie

I have been using cookie authentication in my MVC application. But now that I want to introduce Rest APIs in it, I want the cookie authentication to be only on my MVC part of the application. Is there any configuration to not use these return paths when the URL starts from `/API`

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {

    // Set authentication request paths.
    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Identity/Account/Logout";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
    
    // Set cookies to expire after 2 days.
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(2);

    // Do not update cookie expiration between logins.
    options.SlidingExpiration = false;

    // TODO set HttpOnly? set SecurePolicy to Always?
});
```

I did read the documentation but didn't find any such thing. it is possible with OAuth, but cant find anything in cookie auth.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to change the URL paths in your setup.

I would use attributes on the controllers you want to protect - and not change your startup options.

Put an [Authorize] tag on the controllers you want to force people to sign in on and leave it off for your API controllers with public access.

Comment: Yeah that does work i dont have to authorize, but when i return a 403 status, instead of returning just the status, it returns the access denied path i.e `"/Identity/Account/AccessDenied"`. I just want it to return the 403 status and not get redirected to that page.

Comment: I'd have to see the rest of your code, it's not clear what you are trying to accomplish.  I'm not sure why you'd be trying to return a 403 status from anywhere except the URLs you are trying to protect with the cookie login.

Comment: The cookie authentication is for the MVC part of the code, but there are also rest APIs, for the client to directly get and post data with their own frontend or postman. For that we are just using a secret key for authentication. So if the key is not authenticated we want to return the status. I can definitely show you the code too

Comment: What kind of return statement are you using if the secret key is missing or doesn't match? 
It shouldn't redirect if you specifically return a status code -.... return StatusCode(403);

Comment: i was trying `return forbidden`. but yeah let me try that